# When I call the .getData method using Firebase Storage, it gets skipped over?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-storage

```
func getPost() {
        postCollectionRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let err = error {
                debugPrint("Error getting the data from firebase.")
            } else {
                for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
                    let _data = document.data()
                    let _image = _data["image"] as? String ?? "Anonymous"
                    let _username = _data["username"] as? String ?? "Anonymous"
                    let _location = _data["location"] as? String ?? "Anonymous"
                    let _description = _data["description"] as? String ?? "Anonymous"
                    let _quantity = _data["quantity"] as? String ?? "Anonymous"
                    let _phone = _data["phone"] as? String ?? "Anonymous"
                    let _date = _data["date"] as? Date ?? Date()

                    // Points to the storage
                    let _storageRef = storage.reference()

                    // Points to the images folder
                    let _folderRef = _storageRef.child("images")

                    // Points to the the image under the images folder
                    let _fileRef = _folderRef.child("\(_image).jpg")

                    // File path is "images/whatever.jpg
                    let path = _fileRef.fullPath

                    var loadedImage: UIImage!

                    var temp: [UIImage] = []

//                    _storageRef.child("images/\(_image).jpg")

                    //get the associated post image
                    _fileRef.getData(maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
                        // Create a UIImage, add it to the array
                        if let error = error {
                            print(error)
                        } else {
                            let loadedImage = UIImage(data: data!)
                            temp.append(loadedImage!)
                        }

                    }
```

When I run this code to download an image from firebase storage, it skips over the _fileRef.getData line, and I am not able to get the image from firebase storage. Does anyone know why it would skip over this line instead of go inside it and execute the if else statement?

Edit:
When I set a breakpoint at if let error = error, it actually does append the image to the temp array! However when I try to step out of the _fileRef.getData closure, it keeps taking me into different files but doesn't let me step forward. It first takes me into FIRStorageReference.m, if I try to step over in that file it takes me into 0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release and this pretty much just keeps going on forever and it keeps going into different files. This must be why the line is not executed, does anyone know why this would occur?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on `if let error = error {` does it ever hit that?

Comment: welcome to asynchronous processing.  when you run this it does look like it skips over the getData block, but only because it starts another thread to go do it in the background. if you set a breakpoint inside - like on the error line - you can step through the code in the new thread.    There are lots of good tutorials around on how to handle this sort of thing - good luck